# How to create table from array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table

I have a bit of difficulty creating some tables in a specific order from this array: `$test`.

The array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [ET5] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 430
            )
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 406
            )
        )
    )
    [FA] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 0
            )
        )                   
        [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 0
            )
        )
    )
    [ET5] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 189
            )
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 228
            )
        )
    )
    [FA] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 0
            )
        )
        [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array(
                [total] => 0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

and the tables I want to create should look like this:

table1

```
test1      test2   test3
ET5        430     189
FA         0       0
```

table2

```
test1      test2    test3
ET5        406      228
FA         0        0
```

`test1, test2, test3` are known strings

I'm a bit stuck on this one, notice how the values from the `ET5` are in two tables.

Any ideas on this one?

Comment: Certainly you don't *really* have an array with duplicate key names holding distinct values. Or am I misreading something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely not overwrite the keys of the array like you do above.

I would separate what you want in each tables by adding them as arrays to your already multi-dimensional array...

```
$test = array(
    [0] => array(
        [ET5] => array(), //rest of inner contents inside these arrays of course
        [FA] => array()
    ),
    [1] => array(
        [ET5] => array(),
        [FA] => array()
    )
);
```

then run your foreach loop as you would on any array:

```
<?php foreach($test AS $key => $val): ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Test1</th>
        <th>Test2</th>
        <th>Test3</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($val AS $v => $info): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $v; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info[0][0]['total']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info[1][0]['total']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```